# Approach to trace runner's travelling on map

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am developing an app that record users' travelling path. I have check some tutorial online but it is not helpful enough to me.

Anyone can recommend a tutorial that record users' travelling trace ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please see this example from Ray Wenderlich site :
https://www.raywenderlich.com/97944/make-app-like-runkeeper-swift-part-1